# Replacing data to different file

Tags: python, file

First of all, we have two files:

*file01.txt*

```
101|10075.0|12|24/12/2015
102|1083.33|12|24/12/2015
```

**The second file has only one line!**

*file02.txt*

```
101|False|Section06
```

The first parameter is th same in both files (unique).
I must replace data file01 by some from file02. Match criterion is the first parameter (code).

I have one input (request for code) and readlines for both file what next I need to do Also I'm working with lists.

Expected result:

```
input = 101
```

The output should be:

```
101|False|Section06
102|1083.33|12|24/12/2015
```

Comment: What do you mean? Replace the first file with the second file? Why don't just copy-paste...

Comment: Haha funny ? no my program must do it

Comment: also i have table for both files and can see in terminal data of both files.

Comment: Completely unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Show us your expected results in your question

Comment: What is unclear? i must replace lines in files by input

Comment: @BullzY: Really, it seems like the expect output is replace all lines in `file02.txt` with `file01.txt`. Not?

Comment: ok one second i will edit

Comment: Second file have only one line.

Comment: Okay this makes sense.

Comment: Full program is complex i cant explain whole what i need to do, so this is shortcut that's why doesn't makes sense

Comment: Do you need the change on File1 be written to disk every time you do this?

Comment: Yes.
file02 is temp file, everytime when i open it, it will be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

This works for the given example:

```
with open('file01.txt') as fobj1, open('file02.txt') as fobj2:
    data1 = fobj1.readlines()
    data2 = fobj2.readline()

code = data2.split('|', 1)[0]

with open('file01.txt', 'w') as fobj_out:
    for line in data1:
        if line.split('|', 1)[0] == code:
            fobj_out.write(data2 + '\n')
        else:
            fobj_out.write(line)
```

### Step by step

We open both files for reading:

```
with open('file01.txt') as fobj1, open('file02.txt') as fobj2:
    data1 = fobj1.readlines()
    data2 = fobj2.readline()
```

The read data looks like this:

```
>> data1
['101|10075.0|12|24/12/2015\n', '102|1083.33|12|24/12/2015']

>> data2
'101|False|Section06'
```

We only need the code from `file02.txt`:

```
>>> code = data2.split('|', 1)[0]
code
'101'
```

The `data2.split('|', 1)` splits at `|`.  Since we need only one split, we can limit it with `1`.

Now we open `file01.txt` again. This time for writing:

```
with open('file01.txt', 'w') as fobj_out:
    for line in data1:
        if line.split('|', 1)[0] == code:
            fobj_out.write(data2 + '\n')
        else:
            fobj_out.write(line)
```

This line `if line.split('|', 1)[0] == code:` does the same split as above but for all lines of `file01.txt`. If the code is equal to the one from `file02.txt`, we use the line from `file02.txt`, otherwise we just write the line form `file01.txt` back.

Comment: split('|', 1). for what is "1" ?

Comment: It splits at `|` but only once: `['101', 'False|Section06']'`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) to read the file, and put them in a dict, then replace the keys like this:

```
import csv
with open('file1') as f:
    d = {i[0]: i[1:] for i in csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')}

with open('file2') as f:
    d.update({i[0]: i[1:] for i in csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')})
```

And `d` looks like:

```
{'101': ['False', 'Section06'], '102': ['1083.33', '12', '24/12/2015']}
```

To get the excepted output:

```
>>> ['|'.join([i[0]]+i[1]) for i in d.items()]
['101|False|Section06', '102|1083.33|12|24/12/2015']
```

And if you want write them into a file:

```
with open('file1', 'w') as f:
    for i in d.items():
        f.write('|'.join([i[0]]+i[1]))
```

Comment: I'm wondering if the time complexity is too high if you have to write the altered table back to File1.

Comment: I said above that i'm working with lists, can u provide me what every line here do ?

Comment: This files are just examples, my line is pretty big , i must isolate it in some temp file and change part by part , and write back to old file on same place.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply concatenate the two sets of data into a single `pandas.DataFrame()`, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[10075.0, 12,'24/12/2015'], [1083.33, 12, '24/12/2015']], index=[101,102], columns=['prc', 'code', 'date'])
'''                    
101|10075.0|12|24/12/2015
102|1083.33|12|24/12/2015
'''
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[False, 'Section06'], [True, 'Section07']], index=[101,102], columns=['Bool', 'Section'])
'''
101|False|Section06
102|True|Section07
'''
pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1, join='outer')
```

Which gives:

```
          prc  code        date   Bool    Section
101  10075.00    12  24/12/2015  False  Section06
102   1083.33    12  24/12/2015   True  Section07
```

Now you can get rid of the columns you don't need (eg using `pandas.Drop()`)

Comment: Problem is, for some lines we need a certain subset of the columns and for others we need the other subset.

Comment: OP changed its question quite substantially since I read it first and answered.  ah..